# html select scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, scrollbar

how do you add a scroll bar to the html select box? is there any javascript library that emulate this behavior?

or is there anyway to redesign, the interface I have 2 select box, items can be shifted to the right select box via >> & <<  Filezilla, norton commander, total commander kind of interface where items can be shifted left and right... (question is how to redesign to see the overflow words in the fixed width select box)

from [this forum post](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?t=7797), pointing to another [example](http://www.vladdy.net/tests/lbie.html), the sample code will overlay using div to show the additional text, but it requires the user to hover on the options. not really the solution I am looking for, though I will use it for the time being.

```
<html>

<body>
<table>
<tr><td>
<select size="4" id="mySelect" style="width:65px;color:#f98ad3;">
    <option value="1" selected>option 1 The Long Option</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5 Another Longer than the Long Option ;)</option>
    <option value="6">option 6</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="button" value=">>"/><br>
<input type="button" value="<<"/>
</td>
<td>
<select size="4" id="mySelect" style="width:65px;color:#f98ad3;">
    <option value="1" selected>option 1 The Long Option</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5 Another Longer than the Long Option ;)</option>
    <option value="6">option 6</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

the target browser is MSIE. from the above code, the user cant see 'option 1 The long Option' etc... and each option supposed to have up to a maximum of 200char.

Answer (score 16):

Horizontal scrollbars in a HTML Select are not natively supported. However, here's a way to create the appearance of a horizontal scrollbar:

**1. First create a css class**

```
<style type="text/css">
 .scrollable{
   overflow: auto;
   width: 70px; /* adjust this width depending to amount of text to display */
   height: 80px; /* adjust height depending on number of options to display */
   border: 1px silver solid;
 }
 .scrollable select{
   border: none;
 }
</style>
```

**2. Wrap the SELECT inside a DIV -** also, explicitly set the size to the number of options.

```
<div class="scrollable">
<select size="6" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected>option 1 The Long Option</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5 Another Longer than the Long Option ;)</option>
    <option value="6">option 6</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 this solutions works with IE7 but not IE6 sadly... but it was what I was trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 8):

One options will be to show the selected option above (or below) the select list like following:

**HTML**

```
<div id="selText"><span>&nbsp;</span></div><br/>
<select size="4" id="mySelect" style="width:65px;color:#f98ad3;">
    <option value="1" selected>option 1 The Long Option</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
    <option value="4">option 4</option>
    <option value="5">option 5 Another Longer than the Long Option ;)</option>
    <option value="6">option 6</option>
</select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"   
  type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){        
    $("select#mySelect").change(function(){
      //$("#selText").html($($(this).children("option:selected")[0]).text());
       var txt = $($(this).children("option:selected")[0]).text();
       $("<span>" + txt + "<br/></span>").appendTo($("#selText span:last"));
    });
});
</script>
```

PS:- Set height of div#selText otherwise it will keep shifting select list downward.

Comment: This is a very good answer, but maybe you need to mention that the snippet of javascript requires jQuery.

Comment: Thanks @Jose. I'm working with jQuery since last many days so thought it to be present already!!!

Comment: there is a catch I forgotten to mention, it is a multi select.

Comment: @zeroin23 I've modified code to show list of selected items in the div above select list. Sorry for responding late, very busy :(