# How to add horizontal and vertical scrollbar for <select> tag

Tags: javascript, css

I want to show vertical scrollbar in `<select>` tag because there is more option so I need scrollbar.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901089/html-select-scroll-bar

Comment: Its not according to my requirement.I need to show scrollbar when user click on select box then a dropdown appear that show scroll bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <body>

    <select multiple="yes" style="height: 200px; width: 200px;">
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Note the multiple attribute can be omitted in order to only allow one option to be selected.

Comment: Thanks for reply but actually this select box show drop down automatically but drop down will be show when user click select box down arrow(display in right side)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use a custom drop down element if you need styling on the list itself as you don't have much control on styling the default select drop down. The vertical scroll bar should appear when they're more elements than to fit the display area.

Comment: Meaning that you have a input read only and an image near it with the down arrow and on click you display container under it. This could be easily implemented with jQuery.

Comment: ya but i don't have any idea of jquery ?

Comment: sorry to take this long, have a look at this article: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/07/28/reinventing-drop-down-with-css-jquery.aspx

Comment: I saw the given demo but there is not any scroll bar when user click select tag.

Comment: well that's the beauty of customs, you can do pretty much anything you like with that piece of code afterward, in there he adds an UL and that will be, if I'm not mistaking the new "drop down list", you can add a CSS class to the UL (or identify it by other selectors) and use overflow: visible paired up with some fixed width and height to always show the scroll bars