# Change document scrollable area with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, scroll

I would like to implement a system where opening and overlay changes the browser window's scrollable area to fit that overlay.

I want to do what Twitter's done. As I scroll through tweets, there is a large scrollable document area. However when I click a user, it opens a "profile summary" and the scrollable area shrinks to fit that summary. I'm not sure where to start. A jQuery solution is preferable.

Comment: what have you tried? You can't expect that people will write all the codes for you.

Comment: may be it will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901089/html-select-scroll-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a pretty simple solution, basically you do this:

```
$("body").css({overflow: "hidden"})
```

Set it to overflow: visible when you are done.

http://jsfiddle.net/BoringCode/7xHMf/1/