# IE 11 select list scroll bar color

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to change the color of scrollbar in the select list on IE 11

The style I am applying works great of elements like DIV SPAN but not working for SELECT.

Please take a look at following fiddle and advise how can we change the color of scrollbar in select list.

http://jsfiddle.net/pareshvarde/0pvrp0La/

```
        body{
            scrollbar-base-color: red !important;        
            scrollbar-track-color: yellow !important;
            scrollbar-arrow-color: blue !important;    
        }
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/

Comment: It will never work in IE on select. What you're using is CSS3 feature that is not compatible with IE.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901089/html-select-scroll-bar Create CSS Class and Wrap the select in a div with this class.

Comment: @lonut the CSS classes I used are compatible with IE and works great with elements like DIV and SPAN. However I need to get it working for SELECT list.